# Python Rock Paper Scissor bug I don't understand

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a rock paper scissor game in Python, and I was quite happy with the result below until I noticed I get the "Not a valid answer" case with the following:

player1 = p and player2 = s

player1 = s and player2 = r

I can't figure out why those cases do not work regarding the code logic below. Other combinations with the same letters work fine for both players.

What did I do wrong?

(I'm using jupyter on anaconda)

```
scoreP1 = 0
scoreP2 = 0
game = True
while game != 'QUIT':
    player1 = input("\nJanken! Player 1, type 'r' for Rock, 'p' for Paper or 's' for Scissor: ")
    player2 = input("Janken! Player 2, type 'r' for Rock, 'p' for Paper or 's' for Scissor: ")
    if(
        (player1=="r" and player2=="s") or
        (player1=="p" and player2=="r") or
        (player1=="s" and player2=="p")
    ):
        print("\nPlayer 1 wins! Congrats! Updating scores...")
        scoreP1+=1
        print("Score player 1:",scoreP1)
        print("Score player 2:",scoreP2)
    elif(
        player1==player2
    ):
        print("\nTie! Updating scores...")
        print("Score player 1:",scoreP1)
        print("Score player 2:",scoreP2)
        
    elif(
        player1 != "r" or
        player1 != "s" or
        player1 != "p" or
        player2 != "r" or
        player2 != "s" or
        player2 != "p"
    ):
        print("\nNot a valid answer. Please type 'r' for Rock, 'p' for Paper or 's' for Scissor.")
    else:
        print("Player 2 wins! Congrats! Updating scores...")
        scoreP2+=1
        print("Score player 1:",scoreP1)
        print("Score player 2:",scoreP2)
    game = input("\nAnother game? Type 'QUIT' to end this, or anything else to continue:")
```

Comment: replace the portion that causes the issue with `player1 not in "rsp" or player2 not in "rsp"`. Because As @Carcigenicate said, `player1 != "s" or player1 != "p"` is always true

Comment: No matter what the player typed, `player1 != "r" or player1 != "s" or player1 != "p"` will always be true.  If they typed "r", then `player1 != "s"` will be true.  If they typed "s", then `player1 != "r"` will be true, etc etc.  You want to use `and` instead of `or`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that for a result that should return "Player 2 wins" (eg player1=="s" and player2=="r") ,  the invalid if block matches:

```
player1 != "r" or
player1 != "s" or
player1 != "p" or
player2 != "r" or
player2 != "s" or
player2 != "p"
```

You probably meant

```
( player1 != "r" and player1 != "s" and player1 != "p" ) 
or ( player2 != "r" and player2 != "s" and player2 != "p" )
```

or, more pythonic:

```
 player1 not in ["s", "p", "r"] or player2 not in ["s", "p", "r"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
elif(
    player1 != "r" or
    player1 != "s" or
    player1 != "p" or
    player2 != "r" or
    player2 != "s" or
    player2 != "p"
):
```

This code block requires one of the lines to be True, in order for the whole elif to be true.

If `player1 == 's'`, the code will say "s is not equal to r" Therefor this list of 'or'-statements must be True.

Answer (score 1):

In your last elif you are testing if player1 or player2 is different from your accepted answers.

```
if (player1 != "r" or player1 != "s"...)
```

This is TRUE because if it is "r" it is not "s", if it is "s" then it is != "r" etc.

You should use **AND** instead of OR when testing if it did not belong in ANY of thiese.
Replace those OR with AND and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be broken down so the evaluation can be properly examined. Take a simpler view of the `elif` condition:

```
player1 != "r" or player1 != "s"
```

Now say, the letter `"s"` is assigned into `player1`. That above condition evaluates as:

```
"s" != "r" or "s" != "s"  # Substitute in the value in the place of player1
True or False             # The first half becomes true, the second false
True                      # Which ends up as true
```

Now say, the letter `"r"` is assigned into `player1`. That top condition evaluates as:

```
"r" != "r" or "r" != "s"  # Substitute in the value in the place of player1
False or True             # The first half becomes false, the second true
True                      # Which ends up as true
```

Note how the result is true again. This condition will always be true. For it to be false, you would have to end up with

```
False or False
```

In the second step of the evaluation, and that isn't possible. `player1` would need to be equal to both `"s"` *and* `"r"` *at the same time*, which, beyond `__eq__` hacks to make a bizarrely behaving object, isn't possible.

---

When in doubt, think up some sample data, plug it in, and see how it evaluates like I showed above. It's great practice, and always helpful while debugging conditions like this.

Answer (score -1):

```
player1 != "r" or
player1 != "s" or
player1 != "p" or
player2 != "r" or
player2 != "s" or
player2 != "p".
```

not only prevents illegal input, it prevents legal input too.

```
player1 = p and player2 = s

player1 = s and player2 = r
```

both match the condition.